# What are costs of disabling interrupts vs LDREX/STREX on Arm Cortex M?

Tags: arm, atomic, interrupt, cortex-m, load-link-store-conditional

On ARM Cortex M, I'm aware of only two ways to achieve atomicity:

1. LDREX/STREX
2. Disable interrupts

Both can be used in a very similar way: For example, define `volatile bool is_locked`, and check / set it either with one of those two methods.

What are the costs in performance for each? I imagine we need to think of two things;

1. Throughput: How many cycles are spent on each, assuming no conflicts
2. Latency: For how long are interrupts delayed

Are there any other tradeoffs between the two?

Comment: artlessnoise's answer on [How to write atomic RMW-sequences on Cortex-M4 in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922900) has some qualitative discussion of this, but not hard numbers.  [Simulating LDREX/STREX (load/store exclusive) in Cortex-M0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5745880) has an answer discussing Cortex-M3 as having very low jitter in interrupt timing, since it can abort an in-progress instruction.  Clearly LL/SC has the advantage if that's important.

Comment: (Unfortunately there's a limit of 5 tags.  I wanted to avoid removing [embedded] since some people with experience might just be following that.  But where you're asking for specific numbers, hopefully people who know where to find the numbers will be following [arm] or [cortex-m].  The 5 tags I picked all clearly apply directly.  I wish there was also room for [cpu-architecture][embedded].  But not [concurrency]; disabling interrupts to get atomicity can only work on a uniprocessor, or between one thread and its own signal/interrupt handlers, not e.g. on multi-core cortex-M chips)